# Getting error while running dbca command as oracle user on linux, please help me on this

Tags: oracle, linux

could someone please help me on the below error to get ride of it:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ dbca
UnsatisfiedLinkError exception loading native library: njni11
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_home/lib/libnjni11.so: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: get
        at oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.get(Native Method)
        at oracle.net.config.Config.getNetDir(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.config.Config.initConfig(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.config.Config.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.NetworkUtils.<init>(NetworkUtils.java:286)
        at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.StepContext.<init>(StepContext.java:332)
        at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.Host.<init>(Host.java:811)
        at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.ui.UIHost.<init>(UIHost.java:258)
        at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.ui.InteractiveHost.<init>(InteractiveHost.java:54)
        at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.Dbca.getHost(Dbca.java:164)
        at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.Dbca.execute(Dbca.java:112)
        at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.Dbca.main(Dbca.java:180)
[oracle@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with (use the appropriate install syntax for your distro)

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

and if that doesn't do the trick, do

```
sudo apt-get install libaio libaio-dev
```

Paul...

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have several Oracle home in your server. 
Check your path environment: ORACLE_HOME/bin should be in first position.

Answer (score 0):

search " libaio.so.1" file in directory,
copy it or move to your path mentioned in error, as /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_home/lib/

and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I Have also faced this error and finally able to resolve. It will occur only if prerequisite have not been met.

Below are the two cases:

1. Oracle binaries which you have downloaded is not supported by the OS.
2. You have not installed the suggested oracle RPM packages.

In my case I was getting this error because of the missing oracle 11g RPM's.

Below are the list of suggested [oracle](https://www.orahow.com/2018/07/dbca-unsatisfiedlinkerror-exception.html) 11g and 12c packages. Just crossverify once and try installing from fresh.

https://www.orahow.com/2018/07/dbca-unsatisfiedlinkerror-exception.html